I'm trying to split a file to fit on my FAT32 flash drive but I keep getting told split: extra operand then part of the file name
I am new to all of this and don't know much but the code used is split -b 4GB Super Smash Bros Brawl [RSBE01] and it says split: extra operand "Bros" and multiple times I've changed the code by adding a -, changing the size, removing the word it says, and also adding/removing the file type (wbfs) but I keep getting it and don't know what to do. Does anyone know how to fix this? I've spent two days looking online for help. I'm just trying to play it on my Wii.
Update: I removed all the spaces in the file name and now it says Split: cannot open 'SuperSmashBrosBrawl' for reading. No such file exists or directory. Update 2: Problem solved. Thank you guys for the help

You need to write 4GB  without space.

Use: split -b 4G file.ext

Try a file (rename if necessary) without spaces in its name. The size as GB is powers of 10, as G or GiB is powers of 2.

The usage synopsis for the split command is
split [OPTION]... [FILE [PREFIX]]

So if your filename contains spaces, the first word will be assigned to the FILE operand, the second word will be misinterpreted as a PREFIX, and any subsequent words will be "extra operands".
To avoid this, you need to quote the filename
split -b 4GB 'Super Smash Bros Brawl [RSBE01]'

or
split -b 4GB "Super Smash Bros Brawl [RSBE01]"

or escape the spaces and other shell-special characters:
split -b 4GB Super\ Smash\ Bros\ Brawl\ \[RSBE01\]

